# metrics-spring configuration via .properties file

Tags: java, spring, metrics, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to configure `metrics-spring via configuration file`

In my **spring.xml** I've added

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>
                classpath:metrics.properties
            </value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName"
              value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

filled with something like

```
metrics.reporter.type=console
```

and then I'm setting it in the spring config accessing that property via ${metrics.reporter.type}

```
<metrics:reporter metric-registry="metrics" type="${metrics.reporter.type}" period="1m"/>
```

During the startup of the web application, spring throws a `BeanDefinitionParsingException` due to the `unresolved variable` above

> Configuration problem: No ReporterElementParser found for reporter type '${metrics.reporter.type}'

I'm using this configuration method (via properties file) for mongo host and port and it works like a charm.

I'm running in Tomcat7, Spring 4.0.5.RELEASE, metrics framework 3.1.0-SNAPSHOT (I need jersey 2 support) and metrics-spring 3.0.1. I also tried with a self-compiled metrics-spring 3.1.0-SNAPSHOT but doesn't solve my problem.

[EDIT]

Found this [issue](http://github.com/ryantenney/metrics-spring/issues/81) which explain that SpEL is not supported by the ElementParser.

Comment: Resolving of properties in namespaces has to be implemented by the namespace, it will not be done by spring. Instead of using `${...}` you could try with `#{...}` which is a SpEL expression that might work.

Comment: I tried with     #{metrics.reporter.type} but it doesn't work.

Comment: That won't work as it will try to execute the get moethd on an object called metrics. What is the exception you get with a SpEL expression.

Comment: BeanDefinitionParsingException as before. I thought that maybe metrics-spring make the bean definition validation before the properties are set and then i got this problem.

Comment: Please what exception do you get exactly! Is it the same or is the nested exception a different one. As I stated before support for placeholders has to be build into the namespace by the providers of the namespace.

Comment: Here is full Stackstrace http://pastebin.com/KcXtMwCw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it isn't possible to use a property placeholder in the type attribute.  Spring does not resolve property placeholders or SpEL until the phase after metrics-spring reads the type attribute and parses the reporter element (which is necessary to allow placeholders and bean references to be used in all the other attributes).

A possible solution would be to configure all the reporters you might want to use, and use a placeholder in the enabled attribute:

```
<metrics:reporter metric-registry="metrics" type="console" period="1m"
                  enabled="${metrics.reporter.console.enabled}" />

<metrics:reporter metric-registry="metrics" type="slf4j" period="1m"
                  enabled="${metrics.reporter.slf4j.enabled}" />
```

And the properties file:

```
metrics.reporter.console.enabled=true
metrics.reporter.slf4j.enabled=false
```

I hope this makes sense, I've had a very long week!